# How To Speed Blog With Adsense Fast Loading

Tags: javascript, html, ads, blogger, adsense

I am not sure either this is the stupid question here. But I just try my luck since I want an answer related to Adsense loading on my blog.

I do understand that to get fast loading with Adsense. we have to use only Adsense Javascript but then the blog speed still very bad.

Is there any other best solution to achieve best speed for blogspot blog (Domain)?

I found one blog from Indonesia www.igniel dot com, this blog loading very very fast. I tried to find its Adsense script but then I didn't see any. I am not sure how this site owner did. But I believe something good somewhere.

I hope someone from here can help me on this.

Thanks.

NEWBIE

Comment: Could you please provide some code for us to chceck what is going on? What do you mean by "blog speed"? Does your script loads slowly? Where is it placed? If you are using third-party scripts maybe you should load them [asynchronously](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer)?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did like below
<head>
<link as='script' href='https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js' rel='preload'/>

Comment: And before </body>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
function downloadJSAtOnload(){var d=document.createElement("script");d.src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";d.setAttribute("data-ad-client","ca-pub-1234"),document.body.appendChild(d)}window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("load",downloadJSAtOnload,!1):window.attachEvent?window.attachEvent("onload",downloadJSAtOnload):window.onload=downloadJSAtOnload;
//]]>
</script>

Comment: But then adsense doesn't load nicely. Sometimes it takes a few minutes. I think more than 1 minutes or two. My purpose is to make sure adsense loading as fast. That's all. Tq for your concerns.